# Why won't any changes from NotifyParser render in the UI using Provider / ChangeNotifier / Streambuilder but will from a Service Class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-state, flutter-change-notifier

Per the example code, any data coming from Ble_Service has no problems rendering changes in the UI via provider. But if I pass any of that data from Ble_Service to NotifyParser via changeParserInput() the json string makes it over but no matter the patter I follow I can't get the UI to recognize any state had changed and update the UI beyond the initial seed value.

Ble_Service -> UI //no problem
Ble_Service -> NotifyParserBloc -> UI // Data doesn't make it.

Why?
(the code that is commented out is from the many different variations tried)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/blocs/notifyParser_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/services/bleBelt_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/services/service_locator.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  setupServiceLocator(); // <-- get it service locator function
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotifyParserBloc()),
        //StreamProvider.value(value: NotifyParserBloc().parserInput)
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  //final NotifyParserBloc _notify = NotifyParserBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _service =  Provider.of<BleService>(context);
    //var _bloc = Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("poo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Scan",
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                 _service.startScan();
                },
              )
            ),
            Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Connect",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _service.connectToDevice();
                  },
                )
            ),
            Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Services",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _service.discoverServices();
                  },
                )
            ),
            Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Disconnect",
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _service.disconnectFromDevice();
                  },
                )
            ),
            Consumer<NotifyParserBloc>(
              builder: (context, notifyParserBloc, child) => Text(notifyParserBloc.parserInput)
            ),
            Consumer<BleService>(
                builder: (context, bleService, child) => Text(bleService.viaService)
            ),
            StreamBuilder<String>(
                initialData: "0",
                stream: Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false).parserInputStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  else return Text(
                    snapshot.data.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );}
            ),
//              StreamProvider<String>.value(
//               initialData: "go",
//               value: _bloc.parserInput,
//               child: ValueWidget(),
//           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ValueWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var model = Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context);
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Listening a value :' + Provider.of<String>(context).toString(),),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ble_service

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/services/service_locator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/blocs/notifyParser_bloc.dart';



class BleService with ChangeNotifier {


//NotifyParserBloc _bloc = NotifyParserBloc();
var notifyParser = sl<NotifyParserBloc>();

//class BleService{

  final String TARGET_DEVICE_NAME = "ESP32";
  final String SERVICE_UUID = "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b";
  final String NOTIFY_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8";
  final String WRITE_UUID = "724b0547-3747-4c00-9710-5305a020018f";
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  StreamSubscription<ScanResult> scanSubScription;
  BluetoothDevice beltDevice;
  BluetoothCharacteristic characteristicNotify;
  BluetoothCharacteristic characteristicWrite;
  String bleNotifyString = "";

  //BleBeltNotifyParserBloc _bloc = BleBeltNotifyParserBloc();

  BehaviorSubject<String> _bleStatusFromBeltController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("Disconnected");
  Stream<String> get bleStatusFromBelt => _bleStatusFromBeltController.stream;

  StreamController<String> _bleNotifyFromBeltController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("BLE NOTIFY");
  Stream<String> get bleNotifyFromBelt => _bleNotifyFromBeltController.stream;
  Sink<String> get bleNotifyFromBeltSink => _bleNotifyFromBeltController.sink;

  BehaviorSubject<String> _bleButtonTextController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("button text");
  Stream<String> get bleButtonTextGet => _bleButtonTextController.stream;

  //BleService();

  dispose() {
    _bleStatusFromBeltController.close();
    _bleNotifyFromBeltController.close();
  }

  startScan() {
    stopScan();
//    // SCANNING
    scanSubScription = flutterBlue.scan().listen((scanResult) async {
      if (scanResult.device.name == TARGET_DEVICE_NAME) {
        stopScan();
//        // FOUND
        beltDevice = scanResult.device;
        _bleStatusFromBeltController.add("Found");
        //connectToDevice();
      }
    }, onDone: () => stopScan());
  }

  stopScan() {
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    scanSubScription?.cancel();
    scanSubScription = null;
    _bleStatusFromBeltController.add("Disconnected");
    print("print Disconnected");
  }

  connectToDevice() async {
    if (beltDevice == null) return;
    // CONNECTING
    await beltDevice.connect();
    beltDevice.requestMtu(185);
    print('print DEVICE CONNECTED');
    print(" print BeltDevice $beltDevice");
    _bleStatusFromBeltController.add("Connected");
    print("print Connected");
    //discoverServices();
  }

  discoverServices() async {
    print("discoverServices beltDevice name is  $beltDevice");
    if (beltDevice == null) return;
    List<BluetoothService> services = await beltDevice.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      // do something with service
      if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          // set up notify characteristic
          print("Service Found for $characteristic");
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == NOTIFY_UUID) {
            characteristicNotify = characteristic;
            // tell characteristic on server to notify
            characteristicNotify.setNotifyValue(true);
            print("notify set to true");
            // listen, convert and put notify value in stream
            characteristicNotify.value.listen((value) {
              bleNotifyString = utf8.decode(value);
              //print("got characteristic $value");
              print(bleNotifyString);
              notifyParser.changeParserInput(bleNotifyString);
              print("print Transmitting");
              viaServiceChangeParserInput(bleNotifyString);
              //_bleNotifyFromBeltController.sink.add(bleNotifyString);
              //_bloc.parserInputSink.add(bleNotifyString);
              //_bleStatusFromBeltController.add("Transmitting");

            });
            // COMMUNICATING
          }
          // Prepares characteristic for Write
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == WRITE_UUID) {
            characteristicWrite = characteristic;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  String _viaServiceChangeParserInput = "via Service";
  String get viaService => _viaServiceChangeParserInput;


viaServiceChangeParserInput(String value) {
    _viaServiceChangeParserInput = value;
    print("via Service $_viaServiceChangeParserInput");
    notifyListeners();
}

  disconnectFromDevice() {
    beltDevice.disconnect();
    _bleStatusFromBeltController.add("Disconnected");
    print("Disconnected");
    // DISCONNECTED
  }

  bleButtonText() async {
    _bleStatusFromBeltController.listen((String data) {
      String buttonText;
      if (data == "Disconnected") buttonText = "SCAN";
      else if (data == "Found") buttonText = "CONNECT";
      else if (data == "Connected") buttonText = "DISCONNECT";
      return buttonText;
    });
  }
}
```

Notify Parser

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_belt_provider/services/bleBelt_service.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class NotifyParserBloc with ChangeNotifier{
//  NotifyParserBloc({@required this.bleService});
//  final BleService bleService;
//final BleService bleService;

StreamController<String> _notifyParserController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("parseNotify");
Stream<String> get parserInputStream => _notifyParserController.stream;
//
//  Future<void> parseNotify(String data) async {
//    _notifyParserController.add(data);
//    print("PARSENOTIFYBLOC: $data");
//    _notifyParserController.stream.listen((event) {
//      print("NOTIFYPARSERSTREAM: $event");
//    });
//  }

  String _parserInput;

  NotifyParserBloc(){
    _parserInput = "let's get this started";
  }

  String get parserInput => _parserInput;

  void changeParserInput(String value) {
     _parserInput = value;
     notifyListeners();
     print("change parser value $_parserInput");
     _notifyParserController.add(value);
     _notifyParserController.stream.listen((event) {
      print("NOTIFYPARSERSTREAM: $event");
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `sl<NotifyParserBloc>()` but the var notifyParser inside the BleService it's not the same instance as the one you created in the Provider (so updating/notifying changes to it doesn't actually notify the one depending in the UI). If you want to save an instance in the other provider maybe try something like this

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotifyParserBloc()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService(Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false)),
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
),

class BleService with ChangeNotifier {
   final notifyParser;

   BleService(this.notifyParser); //save the instance in the constructor

   ...
   notifyParser.changeParserInput(bleNotifyString); //now it will update the one using the UI
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can try the same passing a Locator instead of the `Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false)` for readability

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NotifyParserBloc()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService(context.read)), //this is an extension method that allows us to use the Locator
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
),

class BleService with ChangeNotifier {
   final notifyParser;

   BleService(Locator locator) : notifyParser = locator<NotifyParserBloc>(); //save the instance in the constructor

   ...
   notifyParser.changeParserInput(bleNotifyString); //now it will update the one using the UI
}
```

**UPDATE USING GET IT**

If you already had an instance in the getit (sl()) and want to expose it to the provider just change your ChangeNotifierProvider to .value

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: sl<NotifyParserBloc>()), //this will expose the same instance of the get it to the UI
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService())
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
),

class BleService with ChangeNotifier {
   var notifyParser = sl<NotifyParserBloc>();
   // No need for the constructor now

   ...
   notifyParser.changeParserInput(bleNotifyString); //now it will update the one using the UI
}
```

This way the changes to the instance in the get_it will notifiy the UI from the Provider

Comment: Appreciate the help. The sl<NotifyParserBloc>() is a getit call that had just been changed from NotifyParserBloc _bloc = NotifyParserBloc(). With that in place I could call _bloc.changeParserInput(bleNotifyString) getting that json string over to NotifyParser, but then wouldn't make it's way to the UI.

Comment: I took a look at your suggestions. Adding ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService(Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context), listen: false)), gave me an IDE error on listen saying the named parameter isn't defined. It then suggested I add {bool listen} to the line you suggested. BleService(this.notifyParser, {bool listen});  With this change nothing that previously referenced the BleService on the main page works. For example - none of the FlatButtons that call to the Ble Service execute - the method is called on null.

Comment: I can't figure out what to ask google to help me understand this relationship between these two classes and how to pass the data from one to another onto the UI. For example bleService manages the ble and passes it's contents to the notify parser that parses the payload and sends it out to the UI. I have several proof of concepts working where everything is in a single class. But as soon as I break it out - I've run into this roadblock I can't see around.

Comment: Sorry that was my typo mistake, I closed the parentheses before the listen (listen is a named parameter of the of method in Provider) , I edited my code, try again ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BleService(Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false))

Comment: It works. Thank you. Sigh of relief.  What's happening here? You are defining 'notifyParser' in the BleService constructor (this.notifyParser), then using it to locate and call the function changeParserInput() in the NotifyParserBelt class. Am I correct in saying that the data flows through, but the issue was that the UI did not know how to update? By following your suggestion in the provider - BleService(Provider.of<NotifyParserBloc>(context, listen: false) tells the UI to update when calling from BleService to NotifyParser?

Comment: Before this you created a new instance of NotifyParserBloc in BleService, so when you call it with  changeParserInput and use the nofityListeners the UI didn't know because they were listening to the one you created in the MultiProvider (another instance of the class) Imagine like opening 2 databases, one to read and one to write, they don't know each other so writing in one doesn't mean the other will change, also you can try using a Locator to the constructor, similar but less verbose

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. When you say "try using a Locator to the constructor" do you mean when I'm in BleService I use the Locator to make sure I'm not creating a new instance but calling the instance that recognizes the changes being made to the UI - that is called out in Provider? Is there a development term that is used to identify this "original" instance of in NotifyParserBloc that is being managed in Provider? How do you keep track and identify different instances in the IDE? Is "getit" a less verbose locator?

Comment: Oh - great I just saw you added an update! I'll look at that.

Comment: Also a bit ago I had asked a question based on the same type of issue that got downvoted :( -- when I was exploring an inherited widget / bloc architecture. You'll see how I ran into the same issue (lack of knowledge) [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630163/flutter-bloc-a-adds-stream-in-bloc-b-but-this-stream-will-not-render-in-ui-via-s) I gave up there and switched up to learning Provider not figuring out where the issue was. (This issue has allowed me to experiment a lot with different / similar architecture)

Comment: I read it but I don't fully understand the problem (you made a lot of changes to test the stream that I don't know what was the real issue without the tests) but I saw you did the same thing by creating a BleBeltNotifyParserBloc called _bloc inside BleService, and I believe that was the reason it didn't update the UI (for the same reason it didn't work here).

Comment: Also I understand know your first comment saying you created an instance in sl<NotifyParserBloc>(), if you want to keep that instance as a Singleton but used it also to update your UI maybe you could try using ChangeNotifierProvider.value which exposes an already created object (the one you have in the getit) instead of creating it, check my updated answer

Comment: You've provided an amazing answer. I appreciate the time an energy you've put into this. It's very helpful to see how to solve the same problem in three different ways. I can't thank you enough.